# sql server matching 2 table columns for an exact word match

Tags: sql-server, string

I want to search a table's varchar column for content in another table's varchar column.

Certain words are banned and I want to identify the rows that have the banned words. I want an EXACT match on the banned word.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2016.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment](
    [BlogCommentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BlogCommentContent] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_BlogComment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BlogCommentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = 
ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

3 rows - and the data in BlogCommentContent:

There are many of us.

This is the man.

I hear you.

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BannedWords](
    [BannedWordsId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](250) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_BannedWords] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BannedWordsId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = 
ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

3 rows - and the data in Description:

though

man

hear

---

My Sql:

```
SELECT BlogCommentContent
FROM dbo.BlogComment,
     dbo.BannedWords
WHERE ( CHARINDEX( [Description], BlogCommentContent, 1 ) ) > 1
```

It's finding 'man', 'hear' and 'man' in the word 'many'.
So it returns 3 rows.

I only WANT EXACT matches.
So only return 2 rows.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64) 
 Jul  6 2017 07:55:03 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 19043: )

Comment: From the About menu in Sql server Mgmt studio:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  12.0.4100.1
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 12.0.4100.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer   9.11.19041.0
Microsoft .NET Framework   4.0.30319.42000
Operating System    6.3.19043

Comment: Did you  try the proposed solution? One is for 2017, another will work on 2016

Comment: Yes, I did. It produced the correct results. Thanks!

Comment: @Yitzhak One more thing. In my expanded version, I return say 3 columns: BannedWord, UserId and id. 

BannedWord, UserId  id
man                3    42
hear                4    12
about        4    12

How do I remove a duplicate with regard to 'id'? I only want the 1st 2 rows returned (man and hear). I can't use DISTINCT or GROUP BY. I tried to format this nicely but no good.

Comment: Please ask a separate question, and provide a minimal reproducible example. (1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @Yitzhak Actually, using your working solution below that solved my initial problem of doing exact matching on banned words. I just want to take it 1 step further to generate only 1 entry when the source entry has more than 1 distinct banned word in it ie the BlogCommentContent. So, OK, I will create a separate question using the working solution you provided. I just thought I was keeping it simple.

Comment: @Yitzhaf I asked a separate using the solution you provided. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72136456/removing-duplicates-returned-based-on-the-column-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @BlogComment TABLE (
    BlogCommentId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    BlogCommentContent VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @BlogComment (BlogCommentContent) VALUES
('There are many of us.'),
('This is the man.'),
('I hear you.');

DECLARE @BannedWords TABLE (
    BannedWordsId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Word varchar(250))
INSERT INTO @BannedWords (Word) VALUES
('though'),
('man'),
('hear');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT word = TRIM('.,' FROM value ) 
    FROM @BlogComment 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(BlogCommentContent, SPACE(1))
)
SELECT DISTINCT bw.Word 
FROM rs
    INNER JOIN @BannedWords bw ON rs.word = bw.Word;
```

**SQL Server 2016**

```
;WITH rs AS
(
    --SELECT word = TRIM('.,' FROM [value]) 
    SELECT word = REPLACE(REPLACE([value],'.',''),',','')
    FROM @BlogComment 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(BlogCommentContent, SPACE(1))
)
SELECT DISTINCT bw.Word 
FROM rs
    INNER JOIN @BannedWords bw ON rs.word = bw.Word;
```

**Output**

```
+------+
| Word |
+------+
| man  |
| hear |
+------+
```

Comment: I get a red squiqgly line on TRIM and it states: 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.  But of course it is. On the following FROM following '.,' it states: Incorrect syntax near 'FROM'.

Comment: The DDL and inserts work fine.

Comment: Good idea `string_split`. You get my vote.

Comment: I have MS SQL Server 2014. Guess that could be the problem. So TRIM not a built-in function is correct. Is there a 2014 solution to this task of mine?

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact matches what you mean is that there must not be another work touching so man can match "man", "man and women", "mice and men", "a man or two". You need to check

```
BlogCommentContent = 'man'
left(BlogCommentContent,3) = 'man'
right(BlogCommentContent,3) = 'man'
BlogCommentContent like ' man '
```

the length of man can be found with `len('man')` to be used in `right()` and `left()`.
The last value, for `like`, can be constructed with `concat(' ','man',' ')`

Comment: I tried this but got no results back.

SELECT BlogCommentContent
FROM dbo.BlogComment,
           dbo.BannedWords
WHERE ( CHARINDEX( [Description], BlogCommentContent, 1 ) > 1 )
AND LEFT(BlogCommentContent,LEN([Description])) = [Description]
AND RIGHT(BlogCommentContent,LEN([Description])) = [Description]
AND BlogCommentContent LIKE CONCAT(' ',[Description],' ')

Comment: You need `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: Ok, changed it. It brings back the 3 rows.