# Removing duplicates returned based on the column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

This SQL gives me the blog comments that contain just the banned words defined in my table. I only get the EXACT matches and it removes duplicate rows. It also eliminates variants of a banned word. Which is what I want.

```
DECLARE @BlogComment TABLE (
                  BlogCommentId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                  BlogCommentContent VARCHAR(MAX),
                  Id int);
INSERT INTO @BlogComment 
                     (BlogCommentContent, 
                      Id) 
VALUES
('There are many of us.' ,1),
('This is the man.', 2),
('I hear you.', 2),
('Your the man.',2);

DECLARE @BannedWords TABLE (
                   BannedWordsId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                   Word varchar(250));
INSERT INTO @BannedWords (Word) VALUES
('though'),
('man'),
('hear');

;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT word = REPLACE(REPLACE([value],'.',''),',','')
                 ,Id
   FROM @BlogComment 
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(BlogCommentContent, SPACE(1))
)
SELECT DISTINCT bw.Word, 
                rs.id
FROM rs
INNER JOIN @BannedWords bw ON rs.word = bw.Word;
```

---

```
  Results of running this are:
     Word   id
     hear   2
     man    2
```

What I expect.

---

Now I want to take it 1 step further. Test case: I have more than 1 banned word in the same blog comment.

So I altered the code (the table values) to include the test case. A blog comment with 2 banned words.

```
('He is the man. I hear ya.',2),
```

I want only 1 row returned for this case. Either one.

```
     Word   id
     hear   2
```

And altered the code to accommodate this by adding 2 more lines of code per the 'accepted answer' from - [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

---

```
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by Id ORDER BY BlogCommentContent) AS rn
WHERE rn = 1;
```

---

```
DECLARE @BlogComment TABLE (
                  BlogCommentId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                  BlogCommentContent VARCHAR(MAX),
                  Id int);
INSERT INTO @BlogComment 
                     (BlogCommentContent, 
                      Id) 
VALUES
('There are many of us.',1),
('He is the man. I hear ya.',2),
('Your the man.',2);

DECLARE @BannedWords TABLE (
                   BannedWordsId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                   Word varchar(250));
INSERT INTO @BannedWords (Word) VALUES
('though'),
('man'),
('hear');

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT word = REPLACE(REPLACE([value],'.',''),',','')
                  ,Id
                  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by Id ORDER BY BlogCommentContent) AS rn
    FROM @BlogComment 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(BlogCommentContent, SPACE(1))
)
SELECT DISTINCT bw.Word, 
                rs.id
FROM rs
INNER JOIN @BannedWords bw ON rs.word = bw.Word
WHERE rn = 1;
```

---

```
  Results of running this are no rows returned:
      Word  id
```

So, not sure why the 'accepted answer' does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the row_number ... you only need to join split words from each comment and join banned words.. and then count them for each comment ... either all or unique count ..

```
DECLARE @BlogComment TABLE (
                  BlogCommentId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                  BlogCommentContent VARCHAR(MAX),
                  Id int);
INSERT INTO @BlogComment 
                     (BlogCommentContent, 
                      Id) 
VALUES
('There are many of us.',1),
('He is the man. I hear ya.',2),
('Your the man.',2);

DECLARE @BannedWords TABLE (
                   BannedWordsId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                   Word varchar(250));
INSERT INTO @BannedWords (Word) VALUES
('though'),
('man'),
('hear');

SELECT split_words.id as comment_id
, count(bw.Word) as total_banned_words
, count(distinct bw.Word) as total_unique_banned_words
FROM (
    SELECT word = REPLACE(REPLACE([value],'.',''),',','')
                  ,Id
                  ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION by Id,REPLACE(REPLACE([value],'.',''),',','')) cnt
    FROM @BlogComment 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(BlogCommentContent, SPACE(1))
   ) split_words 
LEFT JOIN @BannedWords bw 
ON bw.Word = split_words.word
GROUP BY split_words.id 
ORDER BY split_words.id
```

Comment: Your solution produces stats for me but not the result set I need as stated in my example. And my example was just for demo to get my point across. I will eventually need to apply the final solution to a more complex query that produces a multi-column result set that I pass on to a client app.